# Highlight text in WPF

Tags: wpf, highlight, textblock

Is there a way to dynamically highlight portions of text in a TextBlock? Note that I do not know in advance which parts will need to be highlighted.

Comment: Similar question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751741/wpf-textblock-highlight-certain-parts-based-on-search-condition

Comment: I also posted a HighlightTextBlock as part of an answer for a different question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854570/how-to-implement-a-search-that-causes-multi-column-record-filtering-in-xamdatagr/7956628#7956628)

Comment: AndrewS, just what I was looking for :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display search results in a WPF items control with highlighted query terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728584/how-to-display-search-results-in-a-wpf-items-control-with-highlighted-query-term)