# Format single character in wpf ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, formatting

I'm extending an open source IDE to support a custom programming language.

I made a Difference Engine that check differences from to file. Now I show differences in two wpf listview (tiled vertically).

I know single characters that are different, but in this moment I format the entire row with different foregroung color (as TFS comparer). For added or deleted rows, this is enough. But for changed rows I want to bold or mark the exact char (like WinMerge).

How can I make this?

Thanks to all.
Andrea

EDIT: This is code:

XAML of ListView:

```
    <ListView x:Name="editor" Background="White" Foreground="Black" SelectionMode="Single" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="LNRow" Header="" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LNRow}" Width="75" />
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="LRow" Header="" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LRow}" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Converter={StaticResource WidthConverter}}" />
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="RNRow" Header="" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RNRow}" Width="75" />
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="RRow" Header="" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RRow}" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Converter={StaticResource WidthConverter}}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="2">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="3">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
    </ListView>
```

CodeBehind:

```
        foreach (DiffResultSpan drs in edits)
        {
            switch (drs.Status)
            {
                case DiffResultSpanStatus.NoChange:

                    for (i = 0; i < drs.Length; i++)
                    {
                        dri = new DiffResultItem();
                        dri.LNRow = cntL.ToString("00000");
                        dri.LRow = ((TextLine)source.GetByIndex(drs.SourceIndex + i)).Line;

                        dri.RNRow = cntR.ToString("00000");
                        dri.RRow = ((TextLine)destination.GetByIndex(drs.DestIndex + i)).Line;

                        dri.Type = 0;
                        dri.Tag = drs;
                        dri.Row = row;

                        editor.Items.Add(dri);
                        list.Add(dri);
                        cntL++;
                        cntR++;
                        row++;
                    }

                    break;
                case DiffResultSpanStatus.Replace:

                    for (i = 0; i < drs.Length; i++)
                    {
                        dri = new DiffResultItem();
                        dri.LNRow = cntL.ToString("00000");
                        dri.LRow = ((TextLine)source.GetByIndex(drs.SourceIndex + i)).Line;

                        dri.RNRow = cntR.ToString("00000");
                        dri.RRow = ((TextLine)destination.GetByIndex(drs.DestIndex + i)).Line;

                        dri.Type = 2;
                        dri.Tag = drs;
                        dri.Row = row;

                        editor.Items.Add(dri);
                        list.Add(dri);
                        cntL++;
                        cntR++;
                        row++;
                    }

                    break;
                case DiffResultSpanStatus.DeleteSource:

                    for (i = 0; i < drs.Length; i++)
                    {
                        dri = new DiffResultItem();
                        dri.LNRow = cntL.ToString("00000");
                        dri.LRow = ((TextLine)source.GetByIndex(drs.SourceIndex + i)).Line;

                        dri.RNRow = "";
                        dri.RRow = "";

                        dri.Type = 3;
                        dri.Tag = drs;
                        dri.Row = row;

                        editor.Items.Add(dri);
                        list.Add(dri);
                        cntL++;
                        row++;
                    }

                    break;
                case DiffResultSpanStatus.AddDestination:

                    for (i = 0; i < drs.Length; i++)
                    {
                        dri = new DiffResultItem();
                        dri.LNRow = "";
                        dri.LRow = "";

                        dri.RNRow = cntR.ToString("00000");
                        dri.RRow = ((TextLine)destination.GetByIndex(drs.DestIndex + i)).Line;

                        dri.Type = 1;
                        dri.Tag = drs;
                        dri.Row = row;

                        editor.Items.Add(dri);
                        list.Add(dri);
                        cntR++;
                        row++;
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You'll need a custom control for that. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854570/how-to-implement-a-search-that-causes-multi-column-record-filtering-in-xamdatagr/7956628#7956628) for something similar

Comment: can you show an example with a minimal code?

Comment: @MachineLearning I added sample code

Comment: @Andrea I'd use a `TextBlock` in the `ListView` and multiple `Run`s for the different colors like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11852742/6298965)

Comment: I have to make it at runtime, not in XAML. Is possible? @MachineLearning

Comment: @Andrea yes, for example in the code behind ...if you have a simple case (where is the char and the color to use in your example?) I could write an answer for you, but maybe this comments are just enough to give you the basic idea

Comment: @Andrea this is an [example](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/basic-controls/the-textblock-control-inline-formatting/) from the code behind

Comment: @MachineLearning Thanks a lot.. I'll try in a few minutes.

Comment: Hi @MachineLearning. I added answer with the solution. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved.
I Added a DataTemplate to the column with code. Here XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="editor" Background="White" Foreground="Black" SelectionMode="Single" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Grid.Row="1">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="LNRow" Header="" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LNRow}" Width="75" />
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="LRow" Header="" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LRow}" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Converter={StaticResource WidthConverter}}" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:DiffTextBlock Value="{Binding LRow}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="RNRow" Header="" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RNRow}" Width="75" />
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="RRow" Header="" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RRow}" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Converter={StaticResource WidthConverter}}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="3">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

And I made a Custom TextBlock, DiffTextBlock. This is the code:

```
public class DiffTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(DiffTextBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnContentChanged)));

    public string Value
    {
        get { return GetValue(ValueProperty) as string; }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    static void OnContentChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DiffTextBlock control = target as DiffTextBlock;
        control.createParts(e.NewValue as string);
    }

    void createParts(string text)
    {
        this.Text = "";

        Inlines.Clear();

        // Inlines.Add(text);
        // this.Text = text;
        // Here I write my own algorithm for determine which characters highlight
    }
}
```